# Using JQuery/Javascript to redirect a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

So guys I have a JSP page(`#addressbar` as `< object >`) inside `< div >` of another JSP page(`#homepage`). Is there a way to access(or just redirect) `#homepage` with `Jquery` script which is called by submitting a form in `#adressbar` page? Otherwise when I redirect from `#adressbar` only `< div >` of `#homepage` is changed.

Comment: post the relevant code. what you have tried ??

Comment: This is far too vague. We have no idea what affects *"#homepage is changed"*. Please review [ask] then update question with proper details

Comment: Solved it by using '<jsp:include page="addressbar.jsp" />' instead of '<object data="addressbar.jsp" ></object>'. Redirecting a page using 'include' changes whole page and not just a '<div>'. Sorry for a confusing question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried some thing like this

$( "#addressbar" ).load( "/homepage" );